# How many paths can be unveiled by a single process on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

The OpenBSD manual page for [`unveil`](https://man.openbsd.org/unveil.2) mentions this in the errors section

```
[E2BIG]
    The addition of path would exceed the per-process limit for unveiled paths.
```

Which raises the question, what is the per-process limit of unveiled paths?

Answer (score 1):

## `128`.

From [`sys/kern/kern_unveil.c`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/2b46a8cbba384f799321fc554d4d1c95563ea0a2/sys/kern/kern_unveil.c)

```c
#define UNVEIL_MAX_VNODES   128
#define UNVEIL_MAX_NAMES    128
```

Indeed in `unveil_add`, this is checked

```c
    if (pr->ps_uvvcount >= UNVEIL_MAX_VNODES ||
        pr->ps_uvncount >= UNVEIL_MAX_NAMES) {
        ret = E2BIG;
        goto done;
    }
```

While this doesn't appear to be contractual, this has stayed the same since `unveil` was introduced.

Comment: Kudos for looking up the source code! It's a rare thing and it should be celebrated :)